# Capacitor PPM equivalent?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, passive-components

I have a 10nF capacitor who's datasheet gives 10% tolerance, and 15% total tolerance over temperature (-55 to 125C). It does not give it in ppm, for simulation purposes, how would I calculate it's ppm value?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

ppm means parts per million. 1 ppm is therefore equivalent to 0.0001%. 10% is equivalent to 100,000 ppm. Since this is such a large number, tolerances of this magnitude are not normally quoted in ppm but in percent.

Comment: My SPICE sim does tolerance and temperature effects separately, how would I go about making a simulation over temperature accurate?

Comment: How stable do you need it?

Comment: What do you mean by stable?

Comment: initial error and temperature error

Comment: Well I would like to be able to run Monte Carlo sims at set temperatures and have accurate results, so I guess my answer would be that I would like the two errors completely decoupled from each other.

Comment: You can assume that the initial tolerance is +/-10% at 25°C and that the temperature coefficient is linear and 5% over 180°C (280ppm/°C) depending on the deviation from 25°C. But those are ass-umptions and should be checked with typical curves and so on. It would probably be fairly close to the limits of behavior for a film capacitor, for example.